# value not passing

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I'm trying to send selected checkbox values to another asp page to update database.

```
$("#Delete_selected_Comment_button").click(function () {
    var dataToBeDeleted = new Array();
    $('.checkboxes_to_delete:checked').each(function (key, value) {
        dataToBeDeleted .push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myurl.aspx',
        type: 'GET',
        data: dataToBeDeleted,
        success: function () { alert('yipee'); },
        error: function () { alert("Ooff could not delete data"); }
    });
});
```

Problem:

I am not able to retrieve any value in myurl.asp page.
I am doing:

```
String datagotfromajax= request.QueryString[dataToBeDeleted];
```

Am doing this incorrectly? Where is my  mistake ? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to change one line:

```
data: "ids="+dataToBeDeleted.join(","),
```

And, in the server do:

```
string[] ids = Request.QueryString["ids"].ToString().Split(",");
```

With this you'll hava a string array in the server with the corresponding checkboxes values.

HOpe this helps.

Comment: The `ToString()` is meaningless as it's already a String and you have syntax error, in `C#` it requires square brackets. I would go with `(Request.QueryString["ids"] + "").Split(',');` to avoid exception when no value is passed.

Answer (score 0):

`dataToBeDeleted` will be converted to a query string (if its not already) when sent to the server, that means it consists key-value pairs, i.e. `foo=bar&fred=fish`. On the server you can query **individual** key-value pairs using the syntax

```
string bar = request.QueryString["foo"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array as the `data` parameter.  This won't work.  You need to pass an object.  If the object contains an array, this will be serialized appropriately.  This means your code should probably look like this:

```
data: {
    toBeDeleted: dataToBeDeleted
},
```

This will then be serialized appropriately (see [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param) for the serialization process) and you can retrieve the values with your back-end code.